# Are there rules for flying in difficult weather?

Tags: dnd-5e, flight, weather

There are multiple player races that can fly, including the Aarakocra (comes with a 50' fly speed).

Are there any official rules on how the flight of these races is affected by difficult weather conditions, such as a storm or extreme winds?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Chapter 5 of the *Dungeon's Master Guide* presents some options

The Wilderness Survival section in the Chapter 5 of the *DMG* presents rules for strong wind conditions (pg. 110). It is as follows, emphasis mine:

> A strong wind imposes disadvantage on ranged weapon attack rolls and Wisdom (Perception) checks that rely on hearing. A strong wind also extinguishes open flames, disperses fog, and makes flying by nonmagical means nearly impossible. **A flying creature in a strong wind must land at the end of its turn or fall.**

The rules of heavy precipation in this chapter don't present any guidance regarding flying creatures, but you could make the "flying area" as difficult terrain, effectively halving the flying speed of a creature.

### Weather-related spells can affect flying creatures too

Various weather related spells, such as *control weather*, *control winds*, *gust of wind*, and *wind wall* can be used to hinder/difficult the flight capabilities of a creature.

Answer (score 5):

One option is that the DM might determine the storm to constitute difficult terrain; then the fly speed would be halved.

> [Difficult Terrain](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/adventuring#DifficultTerrain) 
>   You move at half speed in difficult terrain--moving 1 foot in difficult terrain costs 2 feet of speed--so you can cover only half the normal distance in a minute, an hour, or a day.

Comment: It might be worth spending a few more words in general, specifically why the DM would have to make a determination, where there are any rules or guidelines for doing this and possibly how difficult terrain halves the speed (although that may be more preference of wording).

Comment: I don't find any resources or Sage Advice articles that cover this situation.

Comment: Related: [In what cases are the clouds in the sky considered terrain?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/79862/33204)

Comment: The DMG section on Weather (p. 109) might be worth taking a look at

Comment: It might also do to add a comparison to spells that create strong wind effects and how they affect flying creatures. For example, *Gust of Wind* can blast creatures back unless they make strength checks. It doesn't actually specify the wind speed in 5e, but in 3.5 it did specify about 50MPH, so that would probably be a good indicator.

Comment: If we're going to talk about spell enabled flight, strong weather may force concentration checks if particularly violent.